# Reverse SVG line drawing animation

Tags: css, animation, svg, css-animations

I'm trying to reverse how this SVG line animates. I need the line to draw from left to right but can only get it to work right to left. I tried changing the end point in illustrator but this only led to it drawing from both sides. How do I do this? You can see the animation here: http://mckeever02.github.io/voxbit/

This is the SVG:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 759.7 234.2">
    <path class="phone-line" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="4" stroke-dashoffset="20" fill="none" class="st0" d="M755.6,229.7H540.1c-31.9,0-57.6-27-57.6-58.9l0-5.8V61.6c0-31.9-26.1-58-58-58h-40.8h-7.9H335
    M755.6,229.7H540.1c-31.9,0-57.6-27-57.6-58.9l0-5.8V61.6c0-31.9-26.1-58-58-58h-40.8h-7.9H335
        c-31.9,0-58,26.1-58,58v103.3v6.8c0,31.9-26.1,58-58,58H11.55" />
  </svg>
```

and the CSS to animate it:

```
.phone-line {
  stroke-dasharray:1400;
  -webkit-animation: draw 4s ease-in;
}

@-webkit-keyframes draw {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1400;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: On my browser (Firefox/Linux) the line isn't animated at all (as opposed to the icons).

Comment: @rr- Check out in Chrome. He has webkit keyframe rules only.

Comment: Yup, my mistake forgot my non-vendor prefix.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As you would be aware, the `stroke-dasharray` property creates a dashed line pattern. When the value is assigned as 1400 it means that the length of the dash and the space between the dashes is 1400. That is for 0 to 1400 the line will be present and from 1400 to 2800 a dash would be present.

Now when you change the `stroke-dashoffset` from `1400` to `0` it brings the line into view from one direction. Initially the offset is at 1400 and thus only the dash is visible (no line). When the offset is animated to 0, the dash moves out towards the left and the line (that is present from 0 to 1400) slowly comes into view.

A simple method to do it from the other direction would be to animate it from `1400` to `2800`. When this is done, the dash moves out towards the right as the line (that is present from 2800 to 4200) slowly comes into view.

```css
.phone-line {
  stroke-dasharray: 1400;
  animation: draw 4s ease-in;
}
@keyframes draw {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1400;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2800;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<svg viewBox="0 0 759.7 234.2">
  <path class="phone-line" stroke="#000" stroke-width="4" stroke-dashoffset="20" fill="none" class="st0" d="M755.6,229.7H540.1c-31.9,0-57.6-27-57.6-58.9l0-5.8V61.6c0-31.9-26.1-58-58-58h-40.8h-7.9H335
    M755.6,229.7H540.1c-31.9,0-57.6-27-57.6-58.9l0-5.8V61.6c0-31.9-26.1-58-58-58h-40.8h-7.9H335
        c-31.9,0-58,26.1-58,58v103.3v6.8c0,31.9-26.1,58-58,58H11.55" />
</svg>
```

---

Another approach (as mentioned by [Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau) in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32483980/reverse-svg-line-drawing-animation/32484124#comment52829547_32484124)) would be to animate it from `-1400` to `0`. This also produces the same output as the above snippet.

```css
.phone-line {
  stroke-dasharray: 1400;
  animation: draw 4s ease-in;
}
@keyframes draw {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: -1400;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<svg viewBox="0 0 759.7 234.2">
  <path class="phone-line" stroke="#000" stroke-width="4" stroke-dashoffset="20" fill="none" class="st0" d="M755.6,229.7H540.1c-31.9,0-57.6-27-57.6-58.9l0-5.8V61.6c0-31.9-26.1-58-58-58h-40.8h-7.9H335
    M755.6,229.7H540.1c-31.9,0-57.6-27-57.6-58.9l0-5.8V61.6c0-31.9-26.1-58-58-58h-40.8h-7.9H335
        c-31.9,0-58,26.1-58,58v103.3v6.8c0,31.9-26.1,58-58,58H11.55" />
</svg>
```

> **Note:** Ideal approach in my view would be to change the direction of your `path` itself to start from the left and move to the right instead of go from right to left. This is only a simple workaround to reverse the direction without altering the `path`.

Comment: Perhaps simpler still would be to go from `-1400` to `0`.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau: I swear I tried that but for some reason it didn't work earlier. I must have made some silly mistake. Thanks for the comment, I will mention that also in the answer :)

Comment: Confirmed this works in my browser ← by complainer from OP's post

Comment: I was applying this but found that there's a significant delay on the animation starting when compared to forward. Forward starts the animation immediately. I couldn't understand why, can anyone explain that?